# XCM message transfer failed. relaychain report `Error: Barrier`

Tags: polkadot, cumulus, xcm

When I was doing cross-chain messaging (parallel chain A to parallel chain B), parallel chain A sent an XCM message (successfully). After receiving the message, the relay chain was supposed to send it to parallel chain B, but it reported `Error: Barrier`.

This is the log from the relay chain:

[image]

This is my XCM config and ORML config.

```
match_type! {
    pub type ParentOrParentsExecutivePlurality: impl Contains<MultiLocation> = {
        MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: Here } |
        MultiLocation { parents: 1, interior: X1(Plurality { id: BodyId::Executive, .. }) }
    };
}

match_type! {
    pub type SpecParachain: impl Contains<MultiLocation> = {
        MultiLocation {parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(1000))} |
        MultiLocation {parents: 1, interior: X1(Parachain(2000))}
    };
}

pub type Barrier = (
    TakeWeightCredit,
    AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>,
    AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<ParentOrParentsExecutivePlurality>,
    // ^^^ Parent and its exec plurality get free execution
    AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<SpecParachain>,
);

pub struct XcmConfig;
impl xcm_executor::Config for XcmConfig {
    type Call = Call;
    type XcmSender = XcmRouter;
    // How to withdraw and deposit an asset.
    type AssetTransactor = LocalAssetTransactor;
    type OriginConverter = XcmOriginToTransactDispatchOrigin;
    type IsReserve = MultiNativeAsset;
    type IsTeleporter = (); // Teleporting is disabled.
    type LocationInverter = LocationInverter<Ancestry>;
    type Barrier = Barrier;
    type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, Call, MaxInstructions>;
    type Trader = UsingComponents<IdentityFee<Balance>, RelayLocation, AccountId, Balances, ()>;
    type ResponseHandler = PolkadotXcm;
    type AssetTrap = PolkadotXcm;
    type AssetClaims = PolkadotXcm;
    type SubscriptionService = PolkadotXcm;
}
......
......
......
// orml_xtokens
#[derive(Encode, Decode, Eq, PartialEq, Copy, Clone, RuntimeDebug, PartialOrd, Ord, codec::MaxEncodedLen, TypeInfo)]
#[cfg_attr(feature = "std", derive(Serialize, Deserialize))]
pub enum CurrencyId {
    // / Relay chain token.
    ROC,
    // Native TokenSymbol
    A,
    // Parachain B token.
    B,
}

pub type Amount = i128;

pub struct CurrencyIdConvert;
impl Convert<CurrencyId, Option<MultiLocation>> for CurrencyIdConvert {
    fn convert(id: CurrencyId) -> Option<MultiLocation> {
        match id {
            CurrencyId::ROC => Some(Parent.into()),
            CurrencyId::A=> Some((Parent, Parachain(1000), GeneralKey("A".into())).into()),
            CurrencyId::B=> Some((Parent, Parachain(2000), GeneralKey("B".into())).into()),
        }
    }
}
impl Convert<MultiLocation, Option<CurrencyId>> for CurrencyIdConvert {
    fn convert(l: MultiLocation) -> Option<CurrencyId> {
        let a: Vec<u8> = "A".into();
        let b: Vec<u8> = "B".into();
        if l == MultiLocation::parent() {
            return Some(CurrencyId::ROC);
        }
        match l {
            MultiLocation { parents, interior } if parents == 1 => match interior {
                X2(Parachain(1000), GeneralKey(k)) if k == a => Some(CurrencyId::A),
                X2(Parachain(2000), GeneralKey(k)) if k == b => Some(CurrencyId::B),
                _ => None,
            },
            MultiLocation { parents, interior } if parents == 0 => match interior {
                X1(GeneralKey(k)) if k == a => Some(CurrencyId::A),
                X1(GeneralKey(k)) if k == b => Some(CurrencyId::B),
                _ => None,
            },
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
impl Convert<MultiAsset, Option<CurrencyId>> for CurrencyIdConvert {
    fn convert(a: MultiAsset) -> Option<CurrencyId> {
        if let MultiAsset {
            fun: Fungible(_),
            id: Concrete(id),
        } = a
        {
            Self::convert(id)
        } else {
            Option::None
        }
    }
}

pub struct AccountIdToMultiLocation;
impl Convert<AccountId, MultiLocation> for AccountIdToMultiLocation {
    fn convert(account: AccountId) -> MultiLocation {
        X1(Junction::AccountId32 {
            network: NetworkId::Any,
            id: account.into(),
        })
        .into()
    }
}

parameter_types! {
    pub SelfLocation: MultiLocation = MultiLocation::new(1, X1(Parachain(ParachainInfo::parachain_id().into())));
    pub const BaseXcmWeight: Weight = 100_000_000;
    pub const MaxAssetsForTransfer: usize = 2;
}

impl orml_xtokens::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Balance = Balance;
    type CurrencyId = CurrencyId;
    type CurrencyIdConvert = CurrencyIdConvert;
    type AccountIdToMultiLocation = AccountIdToMultiLocation;
    type SelfLocation = SelfLocation;
    type XcmExecutor = XcmExecutor<XcmConfig>;
    type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, Call, MaxInstructions>;
    type BaseXcmWeight = BaseXcmWeight;
    type LocationInverter = LocationInverter<Ancestry>;
    type MaxAssetsForTransfer = MaxAssetsForTransfer;
}

parameter_type_with_key! {
    pub ExistentialDeposits: |currency_id: CurrencyId| -> Balance {
        match currency_id {
            _ => 0,
        }
    };
}

parameter_types! {
    pub ORMLMaxLocks: u32 = 2;
}

impl orml_tokens::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type Balance = Balance;
    type Amount = Amount;
    type CurrencyId = CurrencyId;
    type WeightInfo = ();
    type ExistentialDeposits = ExistentialDeposits;
    type OnDust = ();
    type MaxLocks = ORMLMaxLocks;
    type DustRemovalWhitelist = Nothing;
}

impl orml_xcm::Config for Runtime {
    type Event = Event;
    type SovereignOrigin = EnsureRoot<AccountId>;
}
```

Comment: I actually want Alice's Token_A on parallel chain A to be transferred to Bob on parallel chain B. Currently my parallel chain does not seem to support this operation (because of the problems mentioned above). I suspect a configuration problem with Multilocation and CurrencyId.

Comment: When I was doing cross-chain messaging (parallel chain A to parallel chain B), parallel chain A sent XCM message (successfully). After receiving the message, the relay chain was supposed to send it to parallel chain B, but it reported `Error: Brrier`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem because the Weight value was too low.